# correctly retrieve data with a datetime field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL db with a table containing two fields: `check_date` (of `DATETIME` type) and `CSV_values`. I must extract all the `CSV_values` from:

```
2012-01-10 09:00:00
```

to

```
2012-01-10 10:00:59
```

Is this possible? Is this solution good?

```
SELECT CSV_values WHERE check_date>'2012-01-10 09:00:00' and check_date <'2012-01-10 10:00:59'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider usage of [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator.

```
SELECT CSV_values
 WHERE check_date BETWEEN '2012-01-10 09:00:00' AND '2012-01-10 10:00:59'
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks. I found I forgot FROM clause too.